# How to simplify the expression $((I-A^+A)M(I-A^+A))^+$ when $M$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Denote by $A^+$ the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $A$, by $I$ an identity matrix and by $M$ a symmetric positive-definite matrix. Is it possible to simplify the expression $((I-A^+A)M(I-A^+A))^+$, even if it involves the computation of $M^{-1}$?